# SQL Server: find top 5 elements in a table and all their occurrence in another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with two tables: `hystreal` and `alarm`.

In `alarm`, I have a dictonaries of alarms and an occurrence which increases under some conditions. Since there are some threads that time to time register these alarms, in `hystreal` I register an alarm and the timestamp in which the thread registers it.

Thus, the `hystreal` looks like this:

```
dataregvalue                                        timestamp             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352039            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352049            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352060            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352070            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352081            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352091            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352102            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352112            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352123            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352133            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352144            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352154            
ST8 err. cons.                                      1506352165            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352448            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352458            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352469            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352479            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352490            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352500            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352511            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352532            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352543            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352553            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352564            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352585            
ST7 timeout                                         1506352595            
ST7 timeout                                         1506353273            
ST7 timeout                                         1506353283            
ST7 timeout                                         1506353293            
mac. stop                                           1506353367            
mac. stop                                           1506353399            
mac. stop                                           1506353420            
mac. stop                                           1506353441            
ST3 timeout                                         1506353714            
ST3 timeout                                         1506353724            
ST3 timeout                                         1506353735            
ST3 timeout                                         1506353788            
ST13 timeout                                        1506353809            
ST13 timeout                                        1506353819            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506353893            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506353904            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506353914            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506353925            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506353935            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506353945            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506353956            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506353966            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506353977            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506353988            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506353998            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506354009            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506354019            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506354030            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1506354041            
ST7 timeout                                         1506354157            
ST7 timeout                                         1506354167            
ST7 timeout                                         1506354178            
ST7 timeout                                         1506354188            
ST7 timeout                                         1506354757            
ST7 timeout                                         1506354767            
ST7 timeout                                         1506354778            
ST7 timeout                                         1506354789
```

While, the `alarm` looks like this:

```
communication                                       occur   
------------------------------------------------------------
ST8 err. cons.                                      75            
ST7 timeout                                         15            
mac. stop                                           43            
ST3 timeout                                         7            
ST13 timeout                                        33            
ST23 err. Z42                                       1
```

I would like to find the top 5 `communication` (top 5 based on the value of `occur`) in `alarms` with all their relative timestamp in `hystreal`. How can be done that? Thanks in advance!

N.B.: The number of `timestamp` **IS NOT** related to the value of `occur`. There can be many more `timestamp`.

Comment: I am not understanding what you want for output. Top 5 based on what criteria? Based on your sample data what are you expecting as output?

Comment: I wrote that the top 5 should be based on occur.

Comment: I know you wrote based on value of occur but what does that mean? The largest value, the lowest value? And still don't understand what you expect for output.

Answer (score 2):

It can be as simple as this :

```
Select * from hystreal
where dataregvalue in
(
Select top 5 communication
from alarm
order by occur
)
```